# Open View in Jquery Modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib-grid

i m using Mvc Contrib grid to represent the data, now i want to whenever i click the edit column of the row the Edit view open in a jquery modal,

How can i open a View in Modal?

Thanks,

Saad Tahir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use the link with [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto), or whichever modal plug-in you prefer. With fancybox, your column would look something like this:

```
column.For(item => ActionLink("Edit", "EditAction", "EditController",
    new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "edit-link" });
```

And you should initialize, for instance, Fancybox, with a JavaScript block like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.edit-link').fancybox();
});
```

This would open ~/EditController/EditAction through ajax in a modal. Just remember that EditAction should return a partial view, since it is going to be loaded with ajax.

Comment: a little issue m facing is it opens the modal but also redirect to the view on page and modal disappears.